# How to specify an RGB-format color using XML on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Please give an example of specifying an RGB-formatted color using XML on Android. The syntax is  `#rrggbb`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify an RGB-formatted color in XML like this:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Test text"
            android:textColor="#332116"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

General form:

```
android:textColor="#332116" is "#rrggbb"
```

Comment: Thank Michael But suppose i have the rgb value 147,112,219. How do i specify it?

Comment: Please refer [Link](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm) it is convert RGB to HEX.

Comment: How do you specify aRGB?

Answer (score 3):

To provide any background color

```
android:background="#rrggbb"
```

To provide color to text

```
android:textcolor="#rrggbb"
```

You can use this page to find out the correct RGB value in hexadecimal format

[ColorPicker](http://www.colorpicker.com/)

To specify comments in xml

```
    <!--android:textColor="#332116"-->
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Test text"
            android:textColor="#332116"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Thanks RKN. But can you please tell me how to specify comments in xml

Comment: Thanks once again RKN. You are simply great. I am very much new to android and just learning it

Comment: Hi RKN disturbing you once again. I added the following comments in android xml `<!-- android:textColor="#4169E1" -->` But while compiling an error says `Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)`. Please tell me where i am mistaking?

Comment: where did you put the comment??

Comment: You cannot insert comment there. That is used for specifying the attributes of the **view**(or button here). Put it outside.. See my edit again...